# splitting data in one single row into multiple row in two column

Tags: matlab, row, bounding-box

I have a problem in MATLAB to split my data into multiple row in 2 column.
Currently I have a data of coordinate point  (x,y) from classification in one single row. But I want to split them into multiple rows, so that each row only has two columns.

```
bBox = [289  1  609 1  289  17  369  145  273  161  289 161  561  241  577  241  577  257  689  257  641  273  673  273  641  321  673  321];
```

bBox data is got from boxPoint to create the bounding box for multiple object detection.

Can someone help me to split this data? I want the data to be like:

```
bBOX = [289 1; 609 1; 289 17; .....];
```

my partial code is shown as below:

```
[~, predictions] = svmclassify(P',label,model); % classifying each window

get_detect = predictions.*[predictions > 0.7];

[r,c,v]= find(get_detect);

for i = 1:r
    bBox =cell2mat(boxPoint(r));
    rectangle('Position',[bBox(1),bBox(2),64,128],'LineWidth',1, 'EdgeColor','y');
end
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to write:

```
% Transform bBox into a column vector
bBox = bBox(:); 
% Reshape n-by-1 vector bBox into two columns
bBox = [bBox(1:2:end-1),bBox(2:2:end)];
```

Another is:

```
bBox = reshape(bBox.',2,[]).'
```

Comment: In the last line, I think you mean `reshape(bBox.',2,[]).'`